# Error (InvalidChangeBatch) in adding multiple DNS Records from aws command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-route53

I am trying to add multiple DNS records using this script add_multipleDNSrecord.sh and i am getting this error

```
A client error (InvalidChangeBatch) occurred when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: FATAL problem: UnsupportedCharacter (Value contains unsupported characters) encountered with ' '
```

But i am able to add single record without any issue from aws cli. can anyone please tell me what went wrong in this script?

```
#!/bin/bash
# declare STRING variable
STRING="Hello World"
#print variable on a screen
echo $STRING

# Hosted Zone ID
ZONEID="Z24*************"


#Comment
COMMENT="Add new entry to the zone"

# The Time-To-Live of this recordset
TTL=300

# Type
TYPE="A"

# Input File Name
FILENAME=/home/ec2-user/awscli/route53/scripts/test.json



cat >> $FILENAME << EOF
    {
      "Comment":"$COMMENT",
      "Changes":[
        {
          "Action":"CREATE",
          "ResourceRecordSet":{
            "ResourceRecords":[
              {
                "Value":"$IP"
              }
            ],
            "Name":"$RECORDSET",
            "Type":"$TYPE",
            "TTL":$TTL
          }
        }
      ]
    }
EOF

echo $FILENAME
```

Comment: "Name" (which you're assigning from $RECORDSET) needs to be a valid DNS domain name.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html#domain-name-format-hosted-zones

Comment: if DNS name is the issue it shouldnt work with a single record as well. but i am able to add single DNS record, it fails only when I do with multiple records .

Comment: The file needs to be valid JSON.  If you're just appending one resource block after another, it won't be.

Comment: yeah you are right  that's why i delete the file in the end after adding  the DNS record to the zone. and create a new file again.

Comment: hi karen, thanks for your comment. the space in the DNS domain name is the issue. and instead of space if i use dot like this "ip-00.00.0.$i.http://.dev.abc.net." it works and i am able to multiple records to the hosted zone.

Answer (score 2):

After Replacing the space and using dot instead of space solves the problem.

Now,The script works fine and its able to add multiple records to the hosted zone.