# Iterating through a map of objects with multiple values using for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, dns, terraform, amazon-route53

I have multiple DNS records that I am creating using Terraform. One of my records has two values that it needs to read from. I am having an issue getting Terraform to be able to loop through my variables in order for this to read successfully. Below is my code. I am getting an error that does not make any sense even though I have the correct data type. There is some error with how I am looping through these resources, and I am having some trouble figuring out where I went wrong. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
variables.tf
```

```
    variable "mx" {
      type = map(object({
        ttl     = string
        records = set(string)
      }))
    }
```

```
variables.tfvars
```

```
  mx = {
       "mx_record1" = {
         ttl = "3600"
         records = [
           "mx_record1_value"
         ]
       }
       "mx_record2" = {
         ttl = "3600"
         records = [
           "mx_record2_value"
           "mx_record2_value2"
         ]
       }
```

```
mx.tf
```

```
  locals {
       mx_records = flatten([
         for mx_key, mx in var.mx : [
           for record in mx.records : {
             record = record
             mx     = mx_key
           }
         ]
       ])
     }
 
 resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records" {
   for_each = { for mx in local.mx_records : mx.record => mx }
   zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
   name     = each.key
   type     = "MX"
   ttl      = each.value.ttl
 
   records = [
     each.value.record
   ]
 }
```

Got below error

```
    Error:
    
        Error: Unsupported attribute
    
      on mx.tf line 17, in resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records":
      17:   ttl      = each.value.ttl
        |----------------
        | each.value is object with 2 attributes
    
    This object does not have an attribute named "ttl".
```

UPDATE:

```
    locals {
  mx_records = flatten([
    for mx_key, mx in var.mx : [
      for record in mx.records : {
        record = record
        mx     = mx_key
        ttl    = mx.ttl
      }
    ]
  ])
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records" {
  for_each = { for mx in local.mx_records : mx.record => mx }
  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name     = each.key
  type     = "MX"
  ttl      = each.value.ttl

  records = [
    each.value.record
  ]
}
```

ERROR

```
    Error: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [FATAL problem: UnsupportedCharacter (Value contains unsupported characters) encountered with ' ']
        status code: 400, request id: a27e6a47-c10f-42ce-be94-10aaa9c276f8

  on mx.tf line 13, in resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records":
  13: resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records" {
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your `mx_records` should be:

```
locals {
    mx_records = flatten([
      for mx_key, mx in var.mx :
        [for record in mx.records: {
          record = record
          mx     = mx_key
          ttl    = mx.ttl
        }]
      ])
}
```

This will result in the following structure:

```
mx_records = [
  {
    "mx" = "mx_record1"
    "record" = "mx_record1_value"
    "ttl" = "3600"
  },
  {
    "mx" = "mx_record2"
    "record" = "mx_record2_value"
    "ttl" = "3600"
  },
  {
    "mx" = "mx_record2"
    "record" = "mx_record2_value2"
    "ttl" = "3600"
  },
]
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin. Thank you for the feedback, Couple questions: adding 'record = record' in my local variables means I should also add it in my variables.tf where I declare the "mx" variable? This is a little tricky for me. Adding in 'record = record' in my local variables is giving me a strange error (I will add the error to main question). My output is giving me a logical error where it is taking the value of a record and using it as a key, even though I specified the name of the records should be the key of the map variable. Any additional advice would be helpful

Comment: @DaveMichaels I'm not sure what do you mean. The error message you reported is about `ttl` missing. `record = record` is in the original code that you posted. I modified it so that `ttl` is included, which should address the original error message posted. If  `record` issue is a new one, you can make new question, with the "strange error"  messages, code examples and explanation.

Comment: I apologize. I was getting a little mixed up looking at this new error and comparing to my code. I posted the error I am getting after adding in ttl

Comment: @DaveMichaels  error could be because your `variables.tfvars` has mistakes. The is no comma in between "mx_record2_value"
   and   "mx_record2_value2".

Comment: @DaveMichaels The error is about some strange character somewhere `encountered with ' '`. Maybe you need to check your real mx record file. The dummy values `mx_record2_value2` are not very helpful to verify if your actuall records have correct format. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513831/error-invalidchangebatch-in-adding-multiple-dns-records-from-aws-command-line) is something about R53 records and such an error.